# NumberSlidingPicker cannot integrate with Android java project

Tags: android, build-error, numberpicker

The NumberSlidingPicker is a lightweight library, but I could not able to integrate into my projects

Library link: [sephiroth74-NumberSliderPicker](https://github.com/sephiroth74/NumberSlidingPicker)

While integrate I got the error to add  `"tools: replace=" android:appComponentFactory"` in the manifest file after adding the above I got the following error,

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:358)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
```

Detailed log added [here](https://github.com/sephiroth74/NumberSlidingPicker/issues/4) .

Is there any issue on my side or any solution for this? any suggestions?.

Comment: please share your library version and targetSdkVersion

Comment: implementation 'com.github.sephiroth74:NumberSlidingPicker:v1.0.0'

Comment: targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Is your project migrated to Android X ? If not you can migrate to X and it may solve this issue.

Comment: Still, face the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If your `targetSdkVersion` is lower than 28, then i would recommend you to downgrade your library version, this should resolved the issue.

Comment: targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: implementation 'com.github.sephiroth74:NumberSlidingPicker:v1.0.0'